# bundle install private gem from GitHub actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm setting up GitHub actions for one of our ruby projects and it requires a gem that is from a private repo on GitHub. I know I can check out whatever repo I need with the checkout action, but how do I use that to entitle bundler to login? I could probably setup an SSH key and pass that in as a secret in GitHub actions but I'm wondering if there is another way to do it?